# Remembering context while using NLSQLtablequeryengine , Llamaindex

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, llama-index

Is there a way to take care of context while asking a query with NLSQLtablequeryengine. I am using llamaindex with gpt 3.5

Below is my existing code

```
import os
import logging
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import sqlite3
 
# logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
# logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout))
# import openai
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    MetaData,
    Table,
    Column,
    String,
    Integer,
    select,
    text,
)
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///data/sqlite-sakila.db")
metadata = MetaData()
from llama_index.core import SQLDatabase
 
# with engine.connect() as connection:
#     result = connection.execute(text("select * from film limit 3"))
#     for row in result:
#         print(row)
 
sql_database = SQLDatabase(engine, sample_rows_in_table_info=2)#by default3 (actually)
# print(list(sql_database._all_tables))
tables = list(sql_database._all_tables)
 
from llama_index.core import SQLDatabase
from llama_index.llms.openai import OpenAI
 
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0.1, model="gpt-3.5-turbo")
 
from llama_index.core.query_engine import NLSQLTableQueryEngine
 
query_engine = NLSQLTableQueryEngine(
    sql_database=sql_database, tables=tables, llm=llm
)
query_str = """Identify films that have experienced a significant increase or decrease in rental rate by using the lag function to compare consecutive rental rates."""
 
response = query_engine.query(query_str)
print(response)
print(response.metadata['sql_query'])
```

This is what i am looking to achieve.

**User should be able to ask questions like "Use existing query and add a where clause to it to check whether the film was released before 1999"**